# Can't connect to remote server

Tags: sql-server, networking, remote-access

I am not able to connect to a remote SQL Server.

I have done the following:

1. Enable TCP/IP protocol
2. turned Off the firewall
3. Start SQL Server Browser service.

But I'm still not able to connect to the server

Server Name:--ip\SQLSERVER
User--UserName
Pwd--PWd

Comment: Maybe include the error message so we know what "not able to connect" means.

Answer (score 5):

I would do the following checks.

1. Enable TCP/IP protocol
2. Turn off the firewall on the server (don't know whether you turned off your client firewall or server firewall here)
3. Remote server is up and running
4. Remote server SQL server services are started and running
   a) SQL Server agent
   b) SQL Server (SQLSERVER)
5. Client machine is able to ping remote server (This is not mandatory. If ping is not working still it is possible to access server. If ping is working then one less thing to worry)
6. Finally post your error message if you get any, that will help us understand more clearly what could be wrong.

Comment: HI i am still find the following:--TITLE: Connect to Server

Answer (score 3):

If you haven't already, try the following:

- In Management Studio, right-click your server, and click *Properties*
- Go to the *Connections* page and make sure *Allow remote connections to this server* is checked
- Click on the *Security* page and, under *Server authentication* make sure that *SQL Server and Windows Authentication* mode is selected.

Also, make sure that both the server and client are using the same IP version (`IPv4` or `IPv6`)

Answer (score 0):

Did you check if your user has the right to connect to the server?
Look at the output of:

```
select host, user from mysql.user;
```

it should look like this:

```
+--------------+------------------+
| host         | user             |
+--------------+------------------+
| %            | MyUserName       |
| 12.12.12.123 | MyUserName       |
| localhost    | debian-sys-maint |
| localhost    | mysql.session    |
| localhost    | mysql.sys        |
| localhost    | root             |
+--------------+------------------+
```

Let's look at the first 2 rows, the "%" under host means that you can connect from any IP.
The second row specifies the host (Just pick one of those options).

Hopefully, that helped.